# hide one of the axes of a parallel-coordinates plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axes, parallel-coordinates

i'm representing some data with the parallel coordinates library (based on d3.js) ( https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates#parallel-coordinates )

main functional part of the code is the following:

```
var parcoords = d3.parcoords()("#example")  //#example is the div for the drowing
                    .data(eingabe)          // eingabe is the var, which contains the data     
                    .render()       
                    .reorderable()
                    .shadows()      
                    .brushMode("1D-axes")
```

so far it works fine :)
but now i want to hide one specific axis of the parallel coordinates; i only don't want to show it.

I want that the axis is completeley removed, so that it takes no place and the lines don't be affected of the values of this dimension, but i don´t want to do that by manipulating the data. i only want to manipulate the plot (thats the reason i called it hide).

i've searched on the api description but didn't find something. I searched in the internet but didn't find anything, too. But i think i remember that i've seen a peace of code, where the first axis was hidden, but i can't find it again.
Can anybody tell me, how i can hide an axis or where i can find the solution?
thank you, greetings
Jones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `.hideAxis(array)` method call, where the array is a list of keys of the exact column names in your dataset that you want to hide.  This method does exactly what you said you wanted:

- "...hide one specific axis of the parallel coordinates; i only don't want to show it."
- "I want that the axis is completley [sic] removed, so that it takes no place"
- "the lines dont [sic] be affected of the values of this dimension, but i don´t want to do that by manupulating [sic] the data. i only want to manipulate the plot."

To implement this method, your code would need to be

```
var parcoords = d3.parcoords()("#example")  //#example is the div for the drowing
                    .data(eingabe)          // eingabe is the var, which contains the data
                    .hideAxis(["col1", "col2"])
                    .render()       
                    .reorderable()
                    .shadows()      
                    .brushMode("1D-axes")
```

Note:  `.hideAxis` can take in a blank array if you don't want to hide any axis, i.e. `.hideAxis([])`

You can implement this method in some sort of update/redraw function if you want to allow the user to specify which axis(es) to remove; else, removing it completely via the DOM is impossible.  **This, performing the axis(es) hide via code, is your only option to implement what you want.**

To see this method in action, take a look at the API documentation, specifically, their "example1" graph and code at http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/index.html#example1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to hide the axes (i.e. make it invisible) and not remove it completely

```
d3.selectAll("#example0 > svg > g > g.dimension:nth-child(3)").attr("opacity", "0");
```

Assuming example0 is the id of the wrapper around your svg element. You could also do the same thing directly on your svg element if you have it.

The above would still leave you able to interact with the filter of the hidden axis. To make it non-interactable, use `.attr("display", "none");`

---

Don't have a fiddle, but you should be able to copy paste the above line and run it from the console at http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/ and see the effect on the chart in the Bundling section.

---

Here is the effect - before and after respectively

[image]

Comment: first thank you for the fast good answer:) unfortunately this was not exactly what i was pointing on. I try to improve my question and a pictures

Comment: unefortunately i can´t add pictures yet. i will try to add a better explanation